# Attempting to list all records with a common property, listed by this property

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am lost while trying to write a query for the table below. Passengers can choose from different types of fruit, and I want to list for each fruit, the passengers who have chosen this fruit.

```
pax fruit
1   apple
1   pear
2   mango
3   apple
4   mango
4   pear
```

Output:

```
apple   1   3
pear    1   4
mango   2   4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with SQL is that a query has a fixed set of columns.  So, if you only have two fruits, then this is possible -- you know the result set has three columns.  However, to generalize to more columns, you need to use dynamic SQL.

```
select fruit,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then pax end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then pax end) as col2
from (select pax, fruit,
             row_number() over (partition by fruit order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by fruit;
```